# Accuracy stuck at one point

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am training a sentence classification model and during training I am observing that my model is giving the same accuracy for every epoch. It seems it is stuck at local minima. I have changed optimizers to `sgd`, `rmsprop`, `adam` but nothing is working.

My model code is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 768, input_length=max_len, weights=[embeddings]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(4)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

And compile code is

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD
opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer = opt)
```

This is the training phase

```
Epoch 1/10
1854/1854 [==============================] - 83s 45ms/step - loss: 0.6396 - accuracy: 0.6596 - val_loss: 0.6640 - val_accuracy: 0.6226
Epoch 2/10
1854/1854 [==============================] - 82s 44ms/step - loss: 0.6419 - accuracy: 0.6518 - val_loss: 0.6405 - val_accuracy: 0.6226
Epoch 3/10
1854/1854 [==============================] - 82s 44ms/step - loss: 0.6377 - accuracy: 0.6481 - val_loss: 0.6463 - val_accuracy: 0.6226
Epoch 4/10
1854/1854 [==============================] - 83s 45ms/step - loss: 0.6389 - accuracy: 0.6514 - val_loss: 0.6322 - val_accuracy: 0.6226
Epoch 5/10
1854/1854 [==============================] - 83s 45ms/step - loss: 0.6350 - accuracy: 0.6538 - val_loss: 0.6267 - val_accuracy: 0.6226
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

`metrics=['accuracy']`

to

`metrics=' ['SparseCategoricalAccuracy']`

when using sparse_categorical_crossentropy